# Power automate flow to update the SharePoint list from excel data - Unable to run a flow due to date format error

Tags: power-automate, formatdatetime, createitem

I had a simple power automate flow to read the excel data into SharePoint list. below is the flow that I had used.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
In the create item flow,  i have used the following format for all dates. I don't need the time. I only need date. When I run the flow i get the following error. Please help how to correct this error.

[image: error image]

[image: date format used]

Output: [image: output image]

Comment: Please update your question with the expression you are using for the date format (missing). Include a sample output (of the date) from `List rows present in a table` step.

Comment: Hi, I have added the images showing date format that I used and the output message. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change your date format to `'yyyy-MM-dd'` - this is the format computers like (ISO).

Comment: Apart from updating the format  to 'yyyy-MM-dd', Do I have to update the DateTime format (in Advanced parameters) to ISO 8601?

Comment: Yes - that is correct if your columns in Excel are Date/Time. If you have any more issues, then you need show us the output of your actions (the data).